# Can someone help me identify this bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike

It says it is a Cannondale F400, but it seems those all have forks with suspension.  I am trying to figure out what it is, and it's value, before I move forward with looking at it, but I can't find anything that looks the same, and has the same features.

I can't post the images directly.  Thanks.

http://portland.craigslist.org/mlt/bik/4013428729.html

Comment: Impossible to tell for sure, but it appears to be a 6 or 7 speed rear cassette.  V brakes date the bike to after 1997.  I don't see any images online that appear to have original equipment shocks, though many have the "pretend" bellows below the headset.  Also don't seen any images online of that sort of pseudo Mixte frame unless I drop the "F" from the designation.  This appears to be about the closest: http://www.epinions.com/pr-Bikes-Cannondale_Adventure_400_Mixte?sb=1

Comment: If you look closely at the downtube it says 400. I think they added the F by mistake as a Googling for 'Cannondale 400 hybrid' turns up thousands of bikes that look like this.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking maybe it is the Road Warrior or something along those lines.  Thanks guys.

Comment: You may be able to find a bike that looks the same on classifieds website, Try websites like Gumtree or EuropeGiant that covers all of Europe. I saw ads for bicycles on there. Take a look at http://www.europegiant.com. Good luck !

Comment: This link is long-gone and no information from that link made it here... No way for this to be a useful question for anybody anymore without more info on what's being identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BikePedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2004&brand=Cannondale&model=Adventure+400+Feminine#.UhY_9Bt975Q) has an entry about a bike that looks to be the same as what you posted.

It's a Cannondale Adventure 400 femenine model.  It appears that this came with a front shock initally, but may have been fitted with a rigid front fork (or there were alternate models without the shock).

These appear to have been produced for several years, with a mostly similar design. I'm not quite sure what year that model is.

Comment: I see probably more images without front shocks than with.